# How to target a train summoned via TrainCarts plugin and then /entitydata to set its passenger(Armor Stand)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So how would I have an armor stand set as a passenger on an existing mine cart summoned via TrainCarts (So I can manipulate the minecart's speed while the armor stand is on it)?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to find support outside of vanilla would be wherever you got the plugin (presumably [here](https://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/traincarts/)).

However, if you're playing in 1.9 or later you can use the following command to add a passenger to your minecart: `/entitydata @e[type=MinecartRideable] {Passengers:[{id:"ArmorStand"}]}`

Note that the above is a Mojang-provided command and may or may not break your Bukkit plugin.